# How can I get a regex which gives class name in html codes like class="sampleClass"?

Tags: c#, regex

I want to get all the names of class used in my html file.
I've tried so far in C#

```
String data = Uri.UnescapeDataString(TextBox1.Text);        
    List<string> allClass = new List<string>();
    Match match = Regex.Match(data, "class=\"[^#]+\"");
    if (match.Success)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(match.Captures[0].Value); // Will output "#item3#"
    }
```

but this is not giving the desired result.
as 
my code is

```
<div class="dialogBodyWrapper">
                <div class="dialogBoxContentParent">
                    <p class="mediumText">Changing your authentication details will log you out from the current session
                        and requires re-login with new credentials. Would You like to proceed?</p>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
```

> I want class names in list like dialogBodyWrapper,dialogBoxContentParent,mediumText and clear.

I've tried many regex expression but none is working for me.
Please help me.

Comment: no http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @Traubenfuchs > if you read the thread, you will see this is still in discussion. In that particular case, I don't see why the OP couldn't use regex ... but I may be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save yourself a huge amount of pain, and just use the Html Agility pack from the start...

http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

I strongly agree you should use the HtmlAgilityPack from anything strenuous - however - if this is a one-off script, you may be able to use something like:

```
var classes = Regex
    .Matches(html, @"class=""(.*?)""")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

part of your problem was that you used match instead of matches. also i'd use a regex such as **class="[^"]+"** easy to comprehend regex when you get back to it later.